# How can I hide the card icons in Stripe Payment Element?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

[Stripe Payment Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjB8b.png)

I have to implement Stripe payment for my client. But they don't want the card icons to be seen (MasterCard, Visa etc.)

I couldn't find a way to hide them with Elements Appearance API. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible while using Payment Element. As explained here[1], only public class names can be targeted, private classes such as `.p-CardIcons` are not.

But, if it’s crucial requirement for you,  you can achieve removing the cards icon using Stripe Card Element [2] by setting `hideIcon: true`[3]

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/elements/appearance-api?platform=web#detail-rules

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/card-element

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=card#elements_create-options-hideIcon

Comment: Your answer appears to be for the "Card Element" not Payment Element but it doesn't make it completely clear that you're discussing two different product offerings.